# PostgreSQL - How to insert Base64 images strings into a BYTEA column?

Tags: postgresql, base64, sequelize.js, bytea

I have the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Documents (
  Id INT NOT NULL,
  UserId INT NOT NULL,
  Label CHARACTER VARYING(220) NOT NULL,
  Image BYTEA NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY Key(Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Users(Id)
);
```

I want to know, How should I have to insert the Base64 image into the table.

The Base64 string comes from a Buffer from after getting the image using the [fs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html) module on Node.js.

I'm attempting to insert the image using raw queries of Sequelize, but I have not found proper information on this.

Comment: How do you want to insert the Base64 image? Via SQL statement? Programmatically?

Comment: Programmatically, using [Sequelize's](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) raw queries... I extracted the base64 string from a Buffer using the file system (**fs**) package in Node.js

Comment: You may add this useful information to your question.

Comment: @user871611 I added it, of course I did have to add it in the first place, but due to the lack of info I found on how to insert to the bytea I thought that just asking on the SQL query would be enough, thanks for your patience

Comment: Shouldn't the `decode` function (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-binarystring.html) do the trick? Something like `decode(..., 'base64')`.

Comment: The first parameter should be my base64 plain string?

Comment: Yes. Read the manual in the link I provided.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
insert into table_name (image)
values decode('AcAAFBAO5Az....AQAAAFBCO5gT/AEAABT', 'base64')
```

Here is some information about `decode`

https://www.base64decode.net/postgresql-decode

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question regarding Postgres and Sequelize:

You will need to use the `Sequelize.BLOB('tiny')` datatype to model a `BYTEA` Postgres datatype.

Here is more information about datatypes in Sequelize (it also contains the above information):

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/data-types.html

When converting into a tiny blob, Postgres will default to utf-8, meaning you'll probably want to turn your data into a utf-8 encoding, store the data, and the read it as utf-8.

EDIT:

You will use Base64 to encode the image binary data into an ASCII string:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding