# How to insert and select images in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go, base64, bytea

Given a JSON file of data to be inserted into a table in Postgresql. One of the fields in the JSON structure is a base64 string. I know there is a data type for psql called BYTEA but how would one insert the base64 string in that field.

I also need to then be able to select the base64 string from the table and display the image in the end.

Note: Bonus points for Golang solutions cause the whole app is in Golang

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170508/postgresql-how-to-insert-base64-images-strings-into-a-bytea-column

Comment: @Tyger ty for the insert link, but would I just do an `encode()` ... or is that not a thing. Also, can this be done on the Golang side or does this have to be a psql query?

Comment: you can create a custom type and encode decode in parsing phase

Comment: Just decode to []byte in Go and insert that directly in the database. The JSON decoder will base64-decode automatically.